# How to remove delimiter "-" from the string?

Tags: c#

I have this string:

```
02-37-30-30-30-32-42-34-30-38-45-39-35-03
```

I want to remove the delimiter "-" so that the final output will be:

```
0237303030324234303845393503
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Technology has not reached that level yet.

Comment: hehehe @FarhadJabiyev, that was funny! :D

Comment: maybe some googling will leads you right to the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev The day technology will reach that level, humanity will be doomed.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini It is enough to search exactly same title with that question in google to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 myString.Replace ("-", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried this?

```
stringName.Replace("-", "");
```

This would replace all the `-`s with "" and will remove them.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I am thinking of using the regex. How can I implement it?

Comment: No no, regex is not meant for this. That is a Regular Expression search and replacement or what-so-ever-to-do thing...That is a bit higher level than this!

Comment: Must use regex. It's so much cooler than String.Replace, so it has to be faster, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Regex, (although I'm not sure why that's beneficial) you can do it like this:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(
    "02-37-30-30-30-32-42-34-30-38-45-39-35-03", "-", "");
```